# PHP count occurrence of array items in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of keys ($statuses) to find in a multi-dimensional array ($response). What is the best way to increment the count for each ($statuses) array item?

```
foreach ($response as $feedback) {
    foreach($statuses as $status){
        if($feeedback->status = $status){
            // +1 to each of the status count here
        }
    }
    
}
```

$statuses:

```
array('SHIPPED', 'FAILED', 'COMPLETED');
```

$response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => SHIPPED
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => FAILED     
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => SHIPPED
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => COMPLETED
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => SHIPPED
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => FAILED
            [country] => UNITED STATES
        )
```

So in the above example I would have

```
$shipped = 3;
$failed = 2;
$completed = 1;
```

Comment: Create an array for your output.  Then you can do something like `$output[$status]++;`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat do you have a possible example?

Comment: *What is the best way* + no attempt of doing it yourself + *do you have a possible example?* sounds like *I don't have a clue, please do it for me*.

Comment: @AlanMachado thank you for your useful input

Comment: It would be easier if it was an array of arrays.  Is this decoded JSON?

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array to hold your counts.  Use the status as keys and increment the values.

```
$statuses = array('SHIPPED', 'FAILED', 'COMPLETED');
$output = array_fill_keys($statuses, 0);

foreach ($response as $feedback) {
    foreach($statuses as $status){
        if($feeedback->status === $status){
            $output[$status]++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$response = array(
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'SHIPPED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'FAILED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'SHIPPED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'COMPLETED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'SHIPPED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'status' => 'FAILED',
        'country' => 'UNITED STATES'
    )
);

$results = array();
foreach ($response as $data) {
    // +1 to each of the status count here
    $results[$data->status] = isset($results[$data->status]) ? $results[$data->status]+1 : $results[$data->status] = 1;
}

echo '<pre>';
echo '$results: ' . print_r($results, true);
echo '</pre>';
```